# Trabalho em C "Banco" dando erro

Tags: c, if

Olá estou fazendo um trabalho em c e está dando o seguinte erro: após eu efetuar o Deposito/Saque ao invés de voltar para menu o programa pede para digitar novamente.

```
main(){
  int matriz[5][2],i, j,b,dep,v,a,x,saq,sald;

  printf ("\nBEM VINDO AO BANCO DO BRUNO\n");

  for ( i=1; i<6; i++ ){

    for ( j=1; j<2; j++ )
    {
       printf ("\nDigite o numero da sua conta: ");
       scanf ("%d", &matriz[ i ][ j ]);
       printf("\n Digite o valor do saque inicial : ");
       scanf ("%d",&matriz[i][j+1]);
    }}
    do{

    printf ("\n 1. Efetuar um depósito em uma conta \n 2. Efetuar um saque de uma conta \n 3. Consultar o saldo de uma conta \n 4. Consultar o saldo geral \n 5. Finalizar o programa \n \n QUAL DESEJA ?? ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

     switch(b){
        case 1:
             printf("Digite o numero da conta : ");
             scanf("%d",&a);

            if(a==matriz[1][1]){

                printf("Digite o valor do deposito : ");
                 scanf ("%d",&v);
                dep=matriz[1][2]+v;

                printf("%d",dep);

             }
            else if(a==matriz[2][1]){

                printf("Digite o valor do deposito : ");
                 scanf ("%d",&v);
                dep=matriz[2][2]+v;

                printf("%d",dep);

             }
             if(a==matriz[3][1]){

                printf("Digite o valor do deposito : ");
                 scanf ("%d",&v);
                dep=matriz[3][2]+v;

                printf("%d",dep);

             }
             if(a==matriz[4][1]){

                printf("Digite o valor do deposito : ");
                 scanf ("%d",&v);
                dep=matriz[4][2]+v;

                printf("%d",dep);

             }
             if(a==matriz[5][1]){

                printf("Digite o valor do Deposito : ");
                 scanf ("%d",&v);
                dep=matriz[5][2]+v;

                printf("%d",dep);

             }
             else{
                printf("\n \n \n ESSA CONTA NAO EXISTE \n \n \n");
             }


             case 2:

             printf("Digite o numero da conta : ");
             scanf("%d",&a);

            if(a==matriz[1][1]){

                printf("Digite o valor do Saque : ");
                 scanf ("%d",&x);
                saq=matriz[1][2]-x;

                printf("%d",saq);

             }
             if(a==matriz[2][1]){

                printf("Digite o valor do Saque : ");
                 scanf ("%d",&x);
                saq=matriz[2][2]-x;

                printf("%d",saq);

             }
             if(a==matriz[3][1]){

                printf("Digite o valor do Saque : ");
                 scanf ("%d",&x);
                saq=matriz[3][2]-x;

                printf("%d",saq);

             }
             if(a==matriz[4][1]){

                printf("Digite o valor do Saque : ");
                 scanf ("%d",&x);
                saq=matriz[4][2]-x;

                printf("%d",saq);

             }
             else if(a==matriz[5][1]){

                printf("Digite o valor do Saque : ");
                 scanf ("%d",&x);
                saq=matriz[5][2]-x;

                printf("%d",saq);

             }
             else{
                printf("\n \n \n ESSA CONTA NAO EXISTE \n \n \n");
             }




             case 3:
                printf("Digite o numero da conta : ");
             scanf("%d",&a);

            if(a==matriz[1][1]){

                sald=matriz[1][2];

                printf("\n \n O seu Saldo e de : %d \n",sald);

             }
             if(a==matriz[2][1]){


                sald=matriz[2][2];

                printf("\n \n O seu Saldo e de : %d \n ",sald);

             }
             if(a==matriz[3][1]){


                sald=matriz[3][2];

                printf("\n \n O seu Saldo e de : %d \n ",sald);

             }
             if(a==matriz[4][1]){


                sald=matriz[4][2];

             printf("\n \n O seu Saldo e de : %d \n ",sald);

             }
             if(a==matriz[5][1]){


                sald=matriz[5][2];

                printf("\n \n O seu Saldo e de : %d \n ",sald);

             }
             else{
                printf("\n \n \n ESSA CONTA NAO EXISTE \n \n \n");
             }

     }
     }while (b<5);

    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Você se esqueceu do break nos cases segue o código arrumado abaixo, o break faz com que aquele caso seja executado e depois disso não execute nenhum outro, e roda o "do" novamente

```
main(){ int matriz[5][2],i, j,b,dep,v,a,x,saq,sald;

printf ("\nBEM VINDO AO BANCO DO BRUNO\n");

for ( i=1; i<6; i++ ){

for ( j=1; j<2; j++ )
{
   printf ("\nDigite o numero da sua conta: ");
   scanf ("%d", &matriz[ i ][ j ]);
   printf("\n Digite o valor do saque inicial : ");
   scanf ("%d",&matriz[i][j+1]);
}}
do{

printf ("\n 1. Efetuar um depósito em uma conta \n 2. Efetuar um saque de uma conta \n 3. Consultar o saldo de uma conta \n 4. Consultar o saldo geral \n 5. Finalizar o programa \n \n QUAL DESEJA ?? ");
scanf("%d",&b);

 switch(b){
    case 1:
         printf("Digite o numero da conta : ");
         scanf("%d",&a);

        if(a==matriz[1][1]){

            printf("Digite o valor do deposito : ");
             scanf ("%d",&v);
            dep=matriz[1][2]+v;

            printf("%d",dep);

         }
        else if(a==matriz[2][1]){

            printf("Digite o valor do deposito : ");
             scanf ("%d",&v);
            dep=matriz[2][2]+v;

            printf("%d",dep);

         }
         if(a==matriz[3][1]){

            printf("Digite o valor do deposito : ");
             scanf ("%d",&v);
            dep=matriz[3][2]+v;

            printf("%d",dep);

         }
         if(a==matriz[4][1]){

            printf("Digite o valor do deposito : ");
             scanf ("%d",&v);
            dep=matriz[4][2]+v;

            printf("%d",dep);

         }
         if(a==matriz[5][1]){

            printf("Digite o valor do Deposito : ");
             scanf ("%d",&v);
            dep=matriz[5][2]+v;

            printf("%d",dep);

         }
         else{
            printf("\n \n \n ESSA CONTA NAO EXISTE \n \n \n");
         }

         break;
         case 2:

         printf("Digite o numero da conta : ");
         scanf("%d",&a);

        if(a==matriz[1][1]){

            printf("Digite o valor do Saque : ");
             scanf ("%d",&x);
            saq=matriz[1][2]-x;

            printf("%d",saq);

         }
         if(a==matriz[2][1]){

            printf("Digite o valor do Saque : ");
             scanf ("%d",&x);
            saq=matriz[2][2]-x;

            printf("%d",saq);

         }
         if(a==matriz[3][1]){

            printf("Digite o valor do Saque : ");
             scanf ("%d",&x);
            saq=matriz[3][2]-x;

            printf("%d",saq);

         }
         if(a==matriz[4][1]){

            printf("Digite o valor do Saque : ");
             scanf ("%d",&x);
            saq=matriz[4][2]-x;

            printf("%d",saq);

         }
         else if(a==matriz[5][1]){

            printf("Digite o valor do Saque : ");
             scanf ("%d",&x);
            saq=matriz[5][2]-x;

            printf("%d",saq);

         }
         else{
            printf("\n \n \n ESSA CONTA NAO EXISTE \n \n \n");
         }



         break;
         case 3:
            printf("Digite o numero da conta : ");
         scanf("%d",&a);

        if(a==matriz[1][1]){

            sald=matriz[1][2];

            printf("\n \n O seu Saldo e de : %d \n",sald);

         }
         if(a==matriz[2][1]){


            sald=matriz[2][2];

            printf("\n \n O seu Saldo e de : %d \n ",sald);

         }
         if(a==matriz[3][1]){


            sald=matriz[3][2];

            printf("\n \n O seu Saldo e de : %d \n ",sald);

         }
         if(a==matriz[4][1]){


            sald=matriz[4][2];

         printf("\n \n O seu Saldo e de : %d \n ",sald);

         }
         if(a==matriz[5][1]){


            sald=matriz[5][2];

            printf("\n \n O seu Saldo e de : %d \n ",sald);

         }
         else{
            printf("\n \n \n ESSA CONTA NAO EXISTE \n \n \n");
         }





         break;

 }
 }while (b<5);

}
```